# Track One Time Login

Tags: users, emails

In my Drupal 7 site, when a user registers they are emailed a one time login link that they can use to set their password using this token: [user:one-time-login-url]. Is there any hook that I can use to update a field in my database so that I can differentiate users who have activated their accounts, versus those who have not clicked on the link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never found a solution for that. I did it always the following way:

- Install the rules module (if you did not work with Drupal's hooks yet - otherwise you could use these hooks for that)
- Then give an user a role like "unconfirmed" as soon as a new user account is created by one rule
- Then define another rule: triggering event is "user logged in", check, if the user has the role "unconfirmed" and if so -> action "Take role away" (do not know now what the action is called in English).

Comment: In absence of any simple hook this is a nice solution. Thanks!